# D8 - Cannot make Custom EntityType translatable

Tags: entities

When I am trying to make a custom entity translatable I get the following error message:

```
The Redirect entity entity type cannot be translatable as it does not define a translatable "langcode" field. in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager->buildBaseFieldDefinitions
```

After checking other modules and the drupal docs I have to define 2 things:

1.) I need to create a translatable "langcode" field
2.) I need to set the entityType annotation to translatable

Still I receive this error.

My annotation of the entityType:

```
@ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "email_confirm_redirect",
 *   label = @Translation("Redirect entity"),
 *   admin_permission = "administer email confirm redirect entity",
 *   base_table = "email_confirm_redirect",
 *   revision_table = "email_confirm_redirect_revision",
 *   data_table = "email_confirm_redirect_field_data",
 *   translatable = TRUE,
 *   handlers = {
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\email_confirm_redirect\Entity\Controller\RedirectListBuilder",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "add" = "Drupal\email_confirm_redirect\Form\RedirectForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\email_confirm_redirect\Form\RedirectForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\email_confirm_redirect\Form\RedirectDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "access" = "Drupal\email_confirm_redirect\RedirectAccessControlHandler",
 *   },
 *   list_cache_contexts = { "user" },
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "title",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid"
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/email_confirm_redirect/{email_confirm_redirect_entity}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/email_confirm_redirect/{email_confirm_redirect_entity}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/structure/email_confirm_redirect/list"
 *   },
 * )
```

The field declaration in my baseFieldDefinition() function:

```
//langcode
        $fields['langcode'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('language')
            ->setLabel(t('Language'))
            ->setTranslatable(true)
            ->setDescription(t('The redirect language code.'))
            ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
                'type' => 'language_select',
                'weight' => 2,
            ));
```

Comment: You actually don't need the `$fields['langcode']` if you call `parent::baseFieldDefinition()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you also need to add it to the entity keys:

```
entity_keys = {
  "id" = "id",
  "label" = "title",
  "uuid" = "uuid",
  "langcode" = "langcode"
}
```

Also make sure you're running `drush entity-updates` and clearing cache when making changes to base fields/annotations.

Comment: I have improved the exception text to include the term `entity_keys`. Please review get it committed to Drupal Core here: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3035130